# Stange Pandas df[column].sum() output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

I'm trying to sum up a df column like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [('name1', 2200, 2200), ('name2', 450, 450)]

column_list = ['name', '2021-01', '2021-02']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[column_list])

date1 = '2021-01'

total = df[date1].sum()

print(total)
```

The df looks like this:

```
    name 2021-01 2021-02
0  name1    2200    2200
1  name2     450     450
```

The output of `print(total)` looks like this:

```
2021-01    2650
dtype: int64
```

and I'm not quite sure why or how to just get the `2650`?

Thanks so much for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should deliver flat `list` as columns rather than `list` of `list`s i.e.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [('name1', 2200, 2200), ('name2', 450, 450)]

column_list = ['name', '2021-01', '2021-02']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=column_list)

date1 = '2021-01'

total = df[date1].sum()

print(total)
```

output

```
2650
```